# C270 webcam keeps freezing in both cheese and teams

Tags: webcam, gstreamer, v4l

I've bought a Logitech webcam c270 for my online course, for some reason the university uses Teams. Both Teams and the C270 are compatible in my ubuntu 20.04.

The webcam works pretty well until it freezes. I've tried in Cheese, and for once it's not teams' fault.
I've also installed gstreamer but it doesn't seem to help.
Can anyone please help ?

Thanks !